# Accessing a JSON object inside HttpResponseMessge using StringContent

Tags: c#, json, http

I have a problem accessing a JSON object inside a HttpResponseMessage that is made using StringContent.

Here's what the JSON Objects looks like:

```
{
    "object": "JOB",
    "entry": [
        {
            "uuid": "1nufisnfiu3-dn3u2irb-dn3ui2fb9-nui2",
            "changed_fields": [
                "status"
            ],
            "time": "2018-09-30 21:57:02"
        }
    ],
    "resource_url": "https://somewebsiteAPI.com/api_1.0/Jobs/1nufisnfiu3-dn3u2irb-dn3ui2fb9-nui2.json"
}
```

Here's my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {

            string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            resp.Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            return resp;
        }
```

My objective here is to get the resource_url json object.

Any help would be so much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem or error message?

Comment: Nothing. It's just that it returns the whole JSON object but I want to get is the Resource_URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to let `JSON` string to be object, then get `resource_url` value.

I would use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to make it.

1. Create your model for Json data.

look like this.

```
public class Entry
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public List<string> changed_fields { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    public string resource_url { get; set; }
}
```

2. use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method let `JSON` string to model.

then get the model `resource_url` property and pass as parameter in `StringContent`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{

    string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    resp.Content = new StringContent(model.resource_url, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return resp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should really let the model binder do its intended roles instead of trying to parse the JSON yourself.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Job model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {

        //...do something with model

        return Ok(model.ResourceUrl);
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Where Job is defined from the provided JSON

```
public partial class Job {
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entry")]
    public Entry[] Entry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resource_url")]
    public Uri ResourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public partial class Entry {
    [JsonProperty("uuid")]
    public string Uuid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("changed_fields")]
    public string[] ChangedFields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
}
```

The model binder would parse the incoming JSON and populate the strongly typed object model defined to match the desired data.